# Generating functions for number of ways to take k servings of food

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

A hungry math major visits the school's cafeteria and wants to know the number of ways sk to take k servings of food, including at least one main course, an even number (possibly zero) of side vegetables, an odd number of rolls, and at least two desserts. The cafeteria's food can be distinguished only in the coarsest way: Every dish is either a main course, a side vegetable, a roll, or a dessert. There is an unlimited supply of each kind of dish available.

I want to determine a closed form for the generating functions, but I'm not sure how to dertermine the combinatorical interpretation.

Comment: To take exactly $k$ servings of food, use $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots)$ to represent taking at least one main course, $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)$ to represent taking an even number of vegetables, $(x+x^3+x^5+\dots)$ to represent taking an odd number of rolls, and one more piece which I'll leave to you to spot the pattern for.  Multiplying these together $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)(x+x^3+x^5+\dots)(\cdots)$ and looking at the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion will tell you how many ways you can take $k$ servings of food.

Comment: You can simplify as well and rewrite this, remembering that $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots = \frac{1}{1-x}$.  There will be at least some nice cancellation for your specific problem that occurs.